# I want to resolve the error message which reads as quoted "There should be one and only one skin in the theme, and we found: <b>0</b>"

Tags: html, css, wordpress, blogger

#CHALLENGE FOR A WEB-DEVELOPER AND STACKOVERFLOW CODERS:
While I am editing my Website's Source_Code on Google's Blogger, I am unable to cope further as while saving the code it shows the error message which reads as quoted "There should be one and only one skin in the theme, and we found: **0**", I am attaching the code below,Need Help from A Person Have a look at the Screenshot And Do suggest ME the errors.
#I had also shared the full source_Code in  Google Drive File Link,Please Click On the LInk and do suggest me the Necessary Edits

**SCREENSHOT(QUICK VIEW)**

[image: enter image]

**[SOURCE CODE OF WEBSITE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zUFK37AiwwtQPfCV6vD-foMoSnrZxPyp/view?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its so simple.
add below code in your head section

```
<b:skin><![CDATA[
 /****CSS CODE*****/
 ]]></b:skin>
```

add below code in your Body section

```
<b:section id="1"></b:section>
```

I tested it on your code, and it ran perfectly.

check the below images:-

[image][image]

Comment: ,I am so blissful and thankful that you gave your important time in my Questions, I must Quote "Thanks a billion" to you, But I had only learned python language not HTML coding, so can you look forward into adding                                                                           
    <b:skin><![CDATA[
 /****CSS CODE*****/
 ]]></b:skin> and also adding,<b:section id="1"></b:section> at the right places and then sending me a link where I can find the Source Code edited by you, You may send it here in comment section or to this gmail ID;letsaimforbig@gmail.com, really i am indebted

Comment: Buddy, I edited the code as you said but why did all the images are not showing up, what's wrong can you review once again , here's my site link [link](https://sourcecodeforprogrammes.blogspot.com/), please parth Mangukiya, view the page source and find out the fault.

Comment: Dear @ParthMangukiya , I need your any Contact ID, you are absolutely a Genius , Please Consider Replying me and add your FB, Insta or any Email ID so that I can MAke a contact with a Genius like you.

Comment: tanks for your comment i see but all images are working great

Comment: Dear, Parth as you said **"All images are working great"** so, can you give 2 minutes of your time into sending me a link where you edited the source_code and images were found working, I need that code please, PLease,Consider helping me out